# QML RangeSlider with pivot value

Tags: qt, qml

I'm playing around with RangeSlider and I'm trying to create one with a pivot value where first can't go over and second can't go below that value.

**RangeSliderFixed.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1

Item {
    id: root

    property int minValue: 0
    property int maxValue: 100
    property alias firstValue : rangeSlider.first.value
    property alias secondValue : rangeSlider.second.value
    property int step: 1
    property int pivot: maxValue/2

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Text {
            width: parent.width * 0.15
            height: parent.height
            text: rangeSlider.first.value.toFixed(0)
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }

        RangeSlider {
            id: rangeSlider
            width: parent.width * 0.7
            height: parent.height

            from: minValue
            to: maxValue
            stepSize: step
            snapMode: RangeSlider.SnapAlways

            // binding loop here
            first.value: first.value > pivot ? pivot : first.value
            second.value: second.value < pivot ? pivot : second.value

        }

        Text {
            width: parent.width * 0.15
            height: parent.height
            text : rangeSlider.second.value.toFixed(0)
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    RangeSliderFixed {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

of course there's a binding loop when values surpass the pivot, but I'm quite new to QML and I don't know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

remove that:

```
 // binding loop here
        first.value: first.value > pivot ? pivot : first.value
        second.value: second.value < pivot ? pivot : second.value
```

add following:

```
first.onMove: {
if(first.value > pivot)
    first.value = pivot;
}
```

same for second slider